# How to getProgramAccounts for Token 2022 Program?

Tags: rpc, python, getprogramaccounts, solana-py

I am trying to send get request as follows but it returns nothing...
Can you please guide me how to fix this issue? and how to figure out the datasize and bytes for any program address...

```
{
jsonrpc:"2.0",
id:0,
method:"getProgramAccounts",
params:[
"TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb",
{
encoding:"jsonParsed",
filters:[
{
dataSize:165
},
{
memcmp:{
offset:32,
bytes:"my_wallet_public_address"
       }
}
      ]
}
      ]
}
```

Comment: Solved it! though getTokenAccountsByOwner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because dataSize 165 is for TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, for Token 2022 you should use dataSize:182